# Composer update error: Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I try to configure Laravel 5.2 on windows server 2012 and get an error when executing:

```
composer update
```

> enter code here php artisan clear-compiled
>   
>  
> [ErrorException]
> Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD
>   
>  
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
>   [RuntimeException]
>
> Error Output:
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock]  [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no- progress]
>   [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--pre fer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
>   [--] []....

I have also tries other following artisan command and all they give same error.

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan update
```

> Error
>
> [ErrorException]   Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

Comment: Did you try delete vendor folder and composer install again ?

Comment: i have tried that trick also but it doesn't work

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this unsure if related to nginx as same code works fine on apache but for me adding this to artisan worked 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] : 'GET';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '/';

Comment: Clear the above, I was working on adding the routes through the database and was checking the called route and registering it only if found in the DB for that I was checking on the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] so you most likely are using the variable in one of your files.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by making an empty variable like

```
    $uri = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
```

And if the array variable is set define it, otherwise it'll be an empty string (can also be null but that didn't work for our DB)